# Why is this simple if/else statement not working?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I'm trying to figure out why this doesn't work...

I've two different elements, one positioned at the top of the page, the other one in the bottom half of the page.

I added a bunch of console logs to find out why the wrong class is applied (always 'top', never bottom).

Case 1 Log:

```
.top
half window: 314  top position: 172
```

Case 2 Log:

```
.top
half window: 314  top position: 389
```

On case two, the class **should be** .bottom, but for some reason this simple comparison of two numbers does not work and I've no clue why...

My code:

```
enable_dropdown = (el) ->
  el.closest('.shareable').addClass('active')

  windowheight = $(document).height() / 2
  position = el.offset()
  if position >= windowheight
    el.find('.panel').addClass 'bottom'
    console.log '.bottom'
  else
    el.find('.panel').addClass 'top'
    console.log '.top'
  console.log 'half window: ' + windowheight + '  top position: ' + position.top
```

Comment: What is this sorcery !

Comment: Do you mean to compare `position.top` to `windowHeight`? It looks like you're comparing an object to an integer in the if statement.

Comment: `el.offset() === {top: 10, left: 10}` etc.

Comment: @crclayton thanks, that solved it - completely missed that... `if position.top >= windowheight`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to compare `windowheight` to `position.top`, not `position` (like in your `console.log()` statement).